# ctag parameter is getting added to js file on web page Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, cewp

I am working on CEWP.when I am trying to debug the javascript file.On button click i called a function but function is not getting called becos js file not loaded properly .At the end of js file some ctag paramater got added.

[image]

I would like to know the reason.Please anyone assist me.

Thanks
Swetha

Comment: As @Joe McShea said, purpose of `ctag` is to get alway load the updated/latest file from the source and not the cached version. I do not think this issue is because of `ctag`. Please check if yo are getting any error in console after you click on button. If there is any error, please share the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The ctag is added for cache busting. If you change the source file, the ctag will change, thus the URL changes so the browser will not load an older cached version of the source file. But anything that is added to the URL after the question mark (i.e. parameters) does not affect the loading of the source file by the browser.

If you're JavaScript is not getting loaded, it's not because of the ctag. The most likely reason is that there is a syntax error. In the case of the CEWP, it is not expecting a JavaScript file and will not load it correctly. It's expecting an HTML file. So a JavaScript file that looks like:

```
$().documentReady(function() {});
```

will not get loaded correctly by the CEWP, but:

```
<script type="javascript>
    $().documentReady(function() {});
</script>
```

will get loaded correctly. The first is a JavaScript file, the second is an HTML file with some JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. Create a HTML file and JS file.
2. Upload JS file inside sharepoint
3. get the link of JS and append it to HTML file and then upload the HTML to your sharepoint
4. Get the URL of the html and put inside your CEWP and then try debugging.

Let me know if not working.

Comment: I did the same.

Comment: have a try in incognito.

Comment: tried in incognito also..same issue.and im getting access denied in suiteserviceproxy.aspx..im using enterprise e3 trail version.why i am getting this error any idea?

Comment: Try this.. Create a simple javascript code and a html in the same way as you did previously. Just add a button click and to pop up an alert. If it works then the problem is with your code. You can post code here, if you wish to do so that i can help better